# Liquibase: How do I manage different branches with one database

Tags: liquibase

I have the following problem:

I am working on two different branches: dev, feature1
Both branches work on the same database schema.

Imagine I have **changelog-v1.0 on my dev-branch** und my database fits to that version.

Now if I have **changelog-v1.1 on my feature1-branch** and start my app from there liquibase will apply thhis changes to my database.

From this moment on my app on **dev-branch will not work anymore**, because even though there is no changelog-v1.1 on the dev-branch, the database is already migrated to that version
and if I start my app on the dev-branch liquibase will not roll back the changes of changelog-v1.1.

Working on many branches with different changelog but just one database.
**How do I manage this?**

Answer (score 0):

You can have a master changelog file pointing to children changelog files. But need to make sure to have same files in all branches that have to be merged from dev to feature branch.

Also, note that you have rollback code and tagging in the liquibase changesets in order to successfully rollback changes.